# Specializing a function template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

How do I specialize a function template in c++?

```
#include <iostream>

template <int X = 0>  //Wrong attempt, does not compile.
int func(int y)
{
    return X + y;
}

template<int X>
int func(int y)
{
    return X + func<X-1>(y);
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << func<1>(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like the result of this program to be: 1 + 0 + y  = 3.

For y = 2 it would be: 2 + 1 + 0 + y.

I know there are better ways to do this calculation, I am trying to understand this aspect of the language.

Comment: dont specialize, overload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overloads the function by delegating

```
template <int X>
class Int 
{
};

template <int X>
int funcSwitch(int y, Int<X>)
{
    return X + funcSwitch(y, Int<X-1>());
}

int funcSwitch(int y, Int<0>)
{
    return y;
}

template<int X>
int func(int y)
{
    return funcSwitch(y, Int<X>());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func<1>(2);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to be careful not to define `Int` in another namespace than `funcSwitch`, because then the call in the first `funcSwitch` would not find the second `funcSwitch` case when it is instantiated (this is because of a rule called ADL). To not think about this, you can also write a class template to delegate to

```
template<int X>
struct FuncImpl {
    int operator()(int y) const {
        return X + FuncImpl<X-1>()(y);
    }
};

template<>
struct FuncImpl<0> {
    int operator()(int y) const {
        return y;
    }
};

template<int X>
int func(int y)
{
    return FuncImpl<X>()(y);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func<1>(2);
    return 0;
}
```

In general I prefer the technique without a class, because it allows for member functions to still access `*this` and its private members if `func` were a member function.

To be complete, there is also "explicit specialization" for functions, but because of its limits and pitfalls, I would not recommend it. In this case it would work and would be

```
template<int X>
int func(int y)
{
    return X + func<X-1>(y);
}


template <>
int func<0>(int y)
{
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func<1>(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, is there somewhere that documents the pitfalls?

Comment: Error in funcSwitch: return y; not return X+y;

Comment: Note that overloading + dispatching isn't with pitfalls either. In particular, my example only works because the base case is found by ADL. If `Int` had been defined in some other namespace than the global one, it would fail to work. So for a general dispatching `Int` class, perhaps it would be wise to add an "ADL aux" parameter you could pass an ADL tag declared above your overloads.

Comment: @rileymat the pitfall is that you can't partially specialize function templates and that combined with overloads, it's not trivial to figure out what function will be called. see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22580540/2644390) covers pretty much everything on overloading.

But you can also keep in mind that in some cases, some of the compile-time computations (especially involving scalars of integral types) may be carried out by `constexpr` functions, which are simpler than overloading. In your specific example, this applies:

```
constexpr int f(int x) { return x ? x + f(x-1) : 0; }

template<int x>
int func(int y) { return f(x) + y; }
```

separating the effect of `x` from the effect of `y` (recursion only refers to `x`).

Answer (score 0):

In such case no template specialization is needed. You can simply write the following code using a formula for [a sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum): `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + x = x * (x + 1) / 2`.

```
template <int x>
int func(int y)
{
    return y + x * (x + 1) / 2;
}
```